# Critique my proof of: Suppose $A$, $B$, and $C$ are sets, and $A\setminus B \subseteq C$. Then $A\setminus C \subseteq B$.

Tags: proof-writing, propositional-calculus

I'm back for another proof critique. Any help with structure, correctness, etc. is much appreciated.

*Theorem*. Suppose $A$, $B$, and $C$ are sets, and  $A\setminus B \subseteq C$. Then $A\setminus C \subseteq B$.

*Proof*. Let $x$ be an arbitrary. Suppose $x\in A\setminus C$. Therefore, $x \in A \: \land x \not\in C \implies x \in B \:$ because $A\setminus C \subseteq B$. ASOC that $x \not\in B$. Therefore $x \in A\setminus B$ and $x \in C$ because $A\setminus B \subseteq C$. This is a contradiction because $x \in A\setminus C$. Therefore $x \in B$ and we can conclude that $\forall x(x \in A \land x \not\in C \implies x \in B)$, so $A\setminus C \subseteq B$.

Comment: You want `A \setminus B` etc.

Comment: What's ASOC?___

Comment: Assume for the sake of contradiction.

Comment: As a structure critique, you say “therefore... because” assuming your theorem is already correct in the first place. That sentence is just superfluous, as it doesn’t contribute to the argument or to the flow of the explanation, and it doesn’t really make sense. It would be better to merge the first two sentences together with “Let $x$ be an arbitrary member of $A\setminus C$”, as “let $x$ be an arbitrary” isn’t a complete sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd avoid the usage of so many symbols.

Your proof is too long. Suppose $x\in A\setminus C$. Then $x\in A$ and $x\notin C$. Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $x\notin B$; thus, by definition, we get that $x\in A\setminus B$ and therefore, by assumption, $x\in C$, which is a contradiction. Thus $x\in B$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is good except for the statement 'Therefore, $x \in A \land x \notin C \Rightarrow x \in B$.' Let me correct it to

> The goal is to show that $\forall x:[x \in A \land x \notin C \Rightarrow x \in B]$. Let $x \in A \setminus C$ be arbitrary.

Put the remaining part of your proof after this.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is fine, but you don't need to write the proof by contradiction.

Assume $x \in A \setminus C$.  Then in particular, $x \notin C$.  Since $A \setminus B \subseteq C$, we have $x \notin C \implies x \notin A \setminus B$.  But because $x \in A \setminus C$, we know that $x \in A$, so the additional condition $x \notin A \setminus B$ means that also $x \in B$.  In other words, $x \in A \setminus C \implies x \in B$, and since $x$ is an arbitrary element of $A \setminus C$, it follows that $A \setminus C \subseteq B$.

Comment: It's also a good proof but interpreting $x \notin A\setminus B$ needs more attention than the proof by $\bot$ does. Comment for @FaithAlone: $ \neg (x \in A \land x \notin B)$, $\neg x \in A \lor x \in B$. Therefore, $x \in B$ by resolution.